# The famous counter module "counter" is marked unsupported

Tags: 7

The famous counter module "[Counter](https://drupal.org/project/counter)" is marked unsupported.  Is there another good choice for counter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Visitors](http://drupal.org/project/visitors) module is pretty good option for the counter module.

**Reports provided by the module:**

> 1. View pages that have recently been visited.
> 2. View pages that have been hit frequently.
> 3. View pages count per month.
> 4. View pages count per day of month.
> 5. View pages count per day of week.
> 6. View pages count per hour.
> 7. View pages count per host.
> 8. View access log.
> 9. View user activity report (hits, nodes, comments).
> 10. View referrer list.

Comment: Do you know how to reset the counter to zero?